# How can I Checks for all “Not Secure” Pages?

Tags: http, ssl

I would like to retrieve the url from all the unsecured pages on my site. 
Are there tools for this?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve the url from all the unsecured pages"? List all non-HTTPS pages' URL?

Comment: @shaochuancs List all non-HTTPS  (not secure) pages' URL !

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood well the question, you need to check, by crowling your entire site, for pages alerting the user about "security" issues.

In substance you got to find if any of your site's pages contains an "HTTP:" (not HTTPS) url inside the html code, while browsing yout site on  https://yoursite.com.

If this is the case, i will use wget (to locally download the "rendered" pages of the site locally) and grep (to find any http:// link inside the code) for this task, under linux.

If the site is not generated by a CMS, and you can have access to the sources, I will parse the source files to search for any "HTTP:" inside the code.

BTW, this method does not help you in checking for linked objects (images, scripts...) using unsecure SHA-1 certificates or expired ones even under https://...

Could you kindly further qualify your specific needs?

Best regards.